# Testing/verifying A/B testing with Firebase Remote Config in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, conditional-statements, firebase-remote-config

I'm using Firebase Remote Config to set up an A/B test on iOS.

Everything is set up, and I'm reading the server side default value in the iOS app.

But trying on multiple simulators, they all read the default value.
I suspect, that Google knows I'm the same user, based on my IP, so maybe they're just doing their thing.

**How do I test / verify, that users are getting distributed into the variatons?**

*Here's some more info on my test:*

Since I'm testing a new feature ("Press" or "Hold"), I don't have a baseline/default with no changes.
So in the "Conditions", I've created two conditions. One with "applies if
User in random percentile <= 50 %" and one with "applies if
User in random percentile > 50 %". This will, as I've understood it, direct half the traffic into the 1st condition and the rest into the 2nd condition.
[image: Conditions]

In the "Parameters", I've created one parameter with a value "Hold" for the above 1st condition, value "Press" for the above 2nd condition and "None" for the default value.
[image: Parameter]

Using the parameter key in the iOS app, after fetching, I always get the "None" value on any simulators. I've also tried uninstalling and installing the app multiple times. Always "None"

Firebase will try to see to, that the same user gets the same value/experience every time, so I have to assume that, based on the simulators has the same IP (maybe MAC address from my mac).

I could upload the app to TestFlight and try it out on multiple devices, but this seems rather cumbersome.
There must be a way to test/verify or at least simulate, the 50% distribution I configures in my condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS, you should be able to see different setups simply by deleting and then reinstalling your app.

Try that a few times and, after 6 or 7 tries, if you're still not seeing different results, there might be something wrong with your setup. Either that, or you're incredibly lucky and you should go visit your local roulette table. :)

Comment: Actually, I don't think this is the case. You don't want the framework to re-distribute the same device/user to different variations. This is A/B testing 101. You'd want even distribution, but if the user/client is switching between variations, they could experience different experiences and this would affect the test by confusing the user. You want even distribution, but users/clients that has already been assigned to a certain variation should always be sent to the same variation within the given experiment. This is also how Oprimizely does it. Are you saying that Firebase can't do that?

Comment: Actually, this i partly right. Firebase will keep each app instance in the same variation. So if you delete the app and re-install it, you will be re-distributed. On this part, other A/B testing frameworks solves this better by using a combination of user, device id and app instance, to identify the user.

Comment: In terms of the verification part, I have just found out, that when deleting/reinstalling the app on a simulator, you will be sent to the exact same variation. But doing this on a physical device, will trigger the re-distribution. So: I was able to test the distribution on real devices by deleting and reinstalling the app. Not on the simulator.